# Issue with pygame.transform.rotate(), Index is apparently out of range

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

So I am working on a basic PacMan game, and am trying to get my player to run through its sprite_sheet to show an animation. It works flawlessly when I am moving it right (thats the original orientation of the image), however for any of the other directions where I pygame.transform.rotate() the image, it returns the following:
 self.image = (PAC_UP[self.spritesheet_index % 4])
IndexError: list index out of range

Not sure why this is happening (clearly it has to do with rotation). Any explanation on rotations and why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Heres my code:

```
class sprite_sheet():
    def __init__ (self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename)

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image


PAC_RIGHT = []
for x in range(4):
    image = (sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(x*24, 0, 24, 24))
    PAC_RIGHT.append(image)


PAC_UP = []
for x in range(4):
    image = sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(x*24, 0, 24, 24)
    PAC_RIGHT.append(pygame.transform.rotate(image, 90))

PAC_LEFT = []
for x in range(4):
    image = sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(x*24, 0, 24, 24)
    PAC_RIGHT.append(pygame.transform.rotate(image, 180))

PAC_DOWN = []
for x in range(4):
    image = sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(x*24, 0, 24, 24)
    PAC_RIGHT.append(pygame.transform.rotate(image, 270))





class Player (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.game = game
        self.image = sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(0, 0, 24, 24)

        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.vx, self.vy = 0, 0

        self.spritesheet_index = 0

        self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.delay = 43




    def get_keys(self):
        self.vx, self.vy = 0, 0
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.spritesheet_index += 1



        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.vx = -PLAYER_SPEED
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time-self.first_time > self.delay:
                self.image = (PAC_LEFT[self.spritesheet_index % 4])
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.vx = PLAYER_SPEED
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time-self.first_time > self.delay:
                self.image = (PAC_RIGHT[self.spritesheet_index % 4])
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.vy = -PLAYER_SPEED
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time-self.first_time > self.delay:

                self.image = (PAC_UP[self.spritesheet_index % 4])
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.vy = PLAYER_SPEED
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time - self.first_time > self.delay:
                self.image = (PAC_DOWN[self.spritesheet_index % 4])
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Comment: Because `PAC_UP` is empty. You're only filling `PAC_RIGHT`.

Comment: This is a consequence of copy-pasting. When you have code that needs to be repeated several times and you feel like you need to copy-paste, consider making it a function instead. It'll will reduce the amount of code in your file, make it easier to read, make it easier to change, and it'll avoid these kind of copy-paste bugs.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Okay thanks, was planning on making a function, just wanted to get the basics down. Thanks for the insight (even though my issue was extremely simple)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're only adding your sprite images to the `PAC_UP` list:

```
PAC_RIGHT = []
for x in range(4):
    image = (sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(x*24, 0, 24, 24))
    PAC_RIGHT.append(image)


PAC_UP = []
for x in range(4):
    image = sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(x*24, 0, 24, 24)
    PAC_RIGHT.append(pygame.transform.rotate(image, 90))
```

Modify your code to append to the appropriate lists, `PAC_DOWN`, `PAC_LEFT` & `PAC_RIGHT`.

Additionally, this looks to be a copy-paste error. Instead of copy-pasting, it would be better to create a function to do your image loading.

Here's an untested example:

```
def load_sprite_images(rotation, filename='pacman-spritesheet.png'):
    """Load four sprite images from the specified file"""
    images = []
    for x in range(4):
        image = (sprite_sheet(filename).get_image(x*24, 0, 24, 24))
        images.append(pygame.transform.rotate(image, rotation))
    return images

PAC_RIGHT = load_sprite_images(0)
PAC_UP = load_sprite_images(90)
PAC_LEFT = load_sprite_images(180)
PAC_RIGHT = load_sprite_images(270)
```